# download googlesheet and create folder in specific path to save

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below mentioned code which download google sheet and store it in `Documents`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(googlesheets)
library(rJava)

t.start<-Sys.Date()
t.start<-as.character(t.start)

#gs_auth(new_user = TRUE) 
#gs_ls()
#gs_auth()
as<-gs_title("XYZ")
gs_download(as, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I want the sheet `XYZ` store to a specific location (i.e `E:\My_data\File`) with below mentioned condition.

- I want to Run this script 2 time a day, Where i want to rename the file `XYZ` based on Sys.Date() and with time condition. (For Ex. If Sys.Date=01/01/2017 and time is < 15:00 hrs than name should be `01/01/2017_A_XYZ.xlsx' for >15:00 hrs it should be`01/01/2017_B_XYZ.xlsx')
- I want to automatically create folder in `E:\My_data\File` based on Sys.Date() (i.e Year & Month). If Sys.Date()=01/01/2017 than there would be one folder with name `2017` and one sub folder with name `Jan-17` and in sub folder there would be 2 sub folder `A` (For files <15:00 hrs for that particular Year/Month) and `B` (For files >15:00 hrs for that particular Year/Month).
- If Year/Month change the new folder creates with same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to do that:

```
# To handle the googlesheets
require(googlesheets)

# For easier date manipulation
require(lubridate)

# Get current time
t <- Sys.time()

# Set your base path and create the basic file structure
base_path <- "E:/My_data/File"
dir.create(paste0(base_path, year(t)))
sub_folder_path <- paste0(base_path, year(t), "/", month(t, label = TRUE), "-", day(t))
dir.create(sub_folder_path)

AB_split <- ifelse(hour(t)<15, "A", "B")
dir.create(paste0(sub_folder_path, "/", AB_split))

# Set your gsheet title and the wanted file-name
ws_title <- "XYZ"
ws_file_name <- paste0(date(t), "_", AB_split, "_", ws_title, ".xlsx")
ws_file_path <- paste0(sub_folder_path, "/", AB_split, "/", ws_file_name)

# Download it
as<-gs_title(ws_title)
gs_download(as, to = ws_file_path, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Trying to create an existing folder results if a warning. if you want to surpress the warnings wrap the `create.dir` calls in `suppressWarnings(create.dir(...))`

I would strongly recommend **NOT** to work with the worksheet title but use the key instead. See `?gs_key`

Comment: Thanks, but my gsheet name is static i want to change it after  running the code `as<-gs_title` or before saving it to particular location.

Comment: Sorry my bad...Thanks